# Is there any rule to create new CharacterRun in HWPFDocument?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I can create `CharacterRun` using `paragraph.insertAfter("abc")`/`paragraph.insertBefore("abc")`. But I want to create new fresh CharacterRun. Is there any rule to create `new CharacterRun`?

Comment: Are you using apache-poi? If so, adding this tag may help. Otherwise, please add the library you are using.

Comment: I am using apache tika-parser 1.19 jar